# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Specification to merge with cannot be null in method waitSystemActive

Tags: java, annotations, testng

i am trying to add method with `@Test` and use `dependsOnMethods` in my class.

If I have only 33 `@Test` in this class, it can be run without any errors, but if I try to add only one more `@Test`, I have `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Specification to merge with cannot be null`

I checked, and my `@BeforeClass` does use the testing library.

Please help, I can provide screenshots, if needed.

Comment: Hi Kuzmin!! Could you please add the error stack trace and also a sample code snippet on which you are getting the above issue?

Comment: @VenkataRathnam I tried to test this error again and understood that my trouble in this piece of code:
UsrAppRole roleEndDate = userAppRoles.stream()
                .filter(role -> role4.get_ouid().equals(role4.get_ouid()) && StringUtils.equals(role.getEndDate(), "2091-12-25"))
                .findFirst().get();

If I use it more than 4 times in different Test, this error is happend

I fixed this error, when I replaced this strings on method

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this error, when I replaced same streams on method:
private String getActualEndDate(List userAppRoles, UrengoyApprole appRole) {
return userAppRoles.stream()
.filter(role -> role.get_ouid().equals(appRole.get_ouid()))
.findFirst().get().getEndDate();
}